# фрагменты в viewPager не перелистываются

Tags: android, отладка, gridview, android-viewpager

Разрабатываю приложение для решения матриц, которые отображаются как `gridView` в каждом фрагменте (2 матрицы и один для результата) и того 3 фрагмента для каждой из матриц. Проблема в том, что фрагменты не перелистываются. Показывается только один.

Где может быть ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

main_activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private GridView gridView;
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<Integer, BaseAbstractFragment> fragments = new HashMap<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initFragment();

    }

    private void initFragment() {
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this.fragments);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        CircleIndicator indicator = findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);


        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_first);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                list.add(i + "-" + j);

        }

        gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(list, this);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

    }
}
```

viewPageradapter инициализирую здесь 3 фрагмента в `hashMap`:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Map<Integer, BaseAbstractFragment> pages;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Map<Integer, BaseAbstractFragment> pages) {
        super(fm);
        this.pages = pages;
        initFragments();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return pages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pages.size();
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return (CharSequence) pages.get(position).getTitle();
    }

    //Das nötige Fragment initialisieren
    private void initFragments() {
        pages = new HashMap<>();
        pages.put(0, FirstFragment.getInstance());
        pages.put(1, SecondFragment.getInstance());
        pages.put(2, ResultFragment.getInstance());

    }
}
```

FirstFragment. Один из трёх, они идентичные и наследуют от абстрактного класса:

```
public class FirstFragment extends BaseAbstractFragment {
    public static final int layout = R.layout.fragment_first;
    FirstFragment fragment;

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // getInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
    public static FirstFragment getInstance() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragment.setTitle("first");
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        String message = bundle.getString(fragment.getTitle());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvResult)).setText(message);
        return view;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

и fragment_first.xml для отображения фрагментов:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="56.0dip"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@+string/det" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: зачем внутри initFragment метода делаешь setContentView(R.layout.fragment_first)?

Comment: да, верно, это здесь не нужно, использовал, чтобы посмотреть как отображается GridView.. убрал эту часть кода..теперь фрагменты работают, но теперь при перелистовании, на третьем фрагменте, приложение вылетает.. в чём может быть здесь причина?

Comment: нужно создать новый вопрос и привести отчет об ошибке из locat